# Same attrube name in two class gives error in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes which have different attribute name and joins same class, hibernate gives this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: com.User.userGroupList
```

My model like this:
In group class:

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserGroup> userGroupList;
```

In user Class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<UserGroup> userGroupList;
```

Why it gives this error? Do you have any idea?

Comment: are these classes related in any way?

Comment: Yes bu User and Group separetely related with usergroup class.

Answer (score 0):

At last solved my problem, i have described my column nullable in the database and value in the model class it is nullable also, but i have mistakenly describe my attribute boolean value so primitive type boolean can not be null. So hibernate gives error. But it write console different exception which i have mentioned above. Why hibernate write the console this error to console i dont know but cause of the error was hibernate couldnt handle primitive type is null. Thanks for everyone.